# query null values in http rest

Tags: json, rest, http

Is it even possible? I tried looking and searching here as well, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the JSON of an employee:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "title": "Senior Manager",
  "boss": null,
  "url": "https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/500/400.jpg"
}
```

If I put in my browser:

https://my-json-server.typicode.com/MaverickMeerkat/MockJson/employees?boss=1

I will get the correct data, i.e. all employees who's boss number is 1. But I want to get those who's boss number is null.

I tried the following and nothing works:

```
boss=
boss=null
boss=NUL
boss=%00
```

Comment: Depends on the API, that may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not specify the boss query parameter , anyway this could not be possible .